# Apply backspace within a string

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string which includes backspace.  Displaying it to the commandline will 'apply' the backspaces such that each backspace and the non-backspace character which immediately precedes it cannot be seen:

```
>> tempStr = ['aaab', char(8)]
tempStr =
aaa
```

Yet the deletion operation operation only happens when displaying the string.  It still has the backspace character, and the 'b', inside it:

```
>> length(tempStr)
ans =
 5
```

I'm looking for a minimal (ideally some sort of string processing built in) function which applies the backspace operation:

```
>>f(tempStr)
ans = 
 'aaa'
```

It may also help to know that I have an enumerations class over the alphabet 'a' to 'z' plus ' ' and backspace (to store my own personal indexing of the letters, images associated with each etc.).  It'd be real spiffy to have this backspace removal operation be a method of the superclass that acts on a vector of its objects.

Comment: so something like `newStr = regexprep(tempStr,expression,'');` where `expression = ['\w', char(8)];` ?

Comment: This is very close, thank you!  How about when I start with a backspace or have a double backspace?  `tempStr = [char(8), 'aaabb', char(8), char(8)];`

Comment: But if you start with a backspace, tehre is nothing to delete, rigth?

Comment: correct, but I'd still like the initial backspace removed in newStr

Comment: You can  search for multiples of \ and turn them into one \ and then run the code. Similarly you can check the beginning of your string and remove it if it's a \. But check the options for regexprep, there might be examples of how to do this cleaner

Comment: Hmmm... `sprintf` comes to mind...

Comment: @beaker I just tried that and even though it looks right in the command window, it doesn't change the size of the input.

Comment: @DavidKelley Interesting. So the string returned by `sprintf` is still the same length as the format string? Oh well. I couldn't test it because I'm on Octave right now and the backspace doesn't do *any*thing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a simple function using a while loop:

```
function s = printb(s)

while true

    % Find backspaces
    I = strfind(s, char(8));

    % Break condition
    if isempty(I), break; end

    % Remove elements
    if I(1)==1
        s = s(2:end);
    else
        s(I(1)-1:I(1)) = [];
    end

end
```

and the test gives:

```
s = [char(8) 'hahaha' char(8) char(8) '!'];

numel(s)                 % returns 10

z = printb(s)            % returns 'haha!'

numel(z)                 % returns 5
```

This is not really "minimal", but as far as my knowlegde goes I don't think this is feasible with regular expressions in Matlab.

Best,

Comment: Cool, the only nitpicky comment would be regarding the handling of \\. I'm not sure from the question whether it's supposed to remove 2 characters like you do or just the one prior to the first \ (so remove a\\ in your example). I guess you could just check for consecutive indices in `I` and deal with it that way.

Comment: Nice, very clean.  I was hoping to have the double backspace remove the previous two characters, I believe this solution works but it relies on strfind returning an ascending list of backspace indices (otherwise a backspace could delete another backspace!). I'll accept this answer next week if I can't find a smaller solution.  It seemed like there might be some built-in string processing something (the command line output is printing only our resultant string, right?).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved very elegantly using regular expressions:

```
function newStr = applyBackspaces(tempStr)
    newStr = tempStr;
    while (sum(newStr==char(8))>0)   % while there is at least one char(8) in newStr do:
        tmp    = newStr;             % work on previous result
        if (tmp(1) == char(8))       % if first character is char(8)
            newStr = tmp(2:end);     % then suppress first character
        else                         % else delete all characters just before a char(8)
            newStr = regexprep(tmp,[ '.' char(8)],'');  % as well as char(8) itself.
        end
    end
end
```

In essence, what my function does is delete the character just before the backspace until there are no more backspaces in your input string `tempStr`.

To test if it works, we check the output and the length of the string:

```
>> tempStr = ['abc', char(8), 'def', char(8), char(8), 'ghi']

tempStr =

abdghi

>> length(tempStr)

ans =

    12

>> applyBackspaces(tempStr)

ans =

abdghi

>> length(applyBackspaces(tempStr))

ans =

     6
```

Hence, `tempStr` and `applyBackspaces(tempStr)` show the same string, but `applyBackspaces(tempStr)` is the same length as the number of characters displayed.